# How to increase Chinese character space?

Tags: spacing, characters, cjk

Sometimes the spaces between Characters are too small, especially in book titles which could be seen in the following picture.

[image]
Then my **QUESTION** is *how to increase the space between Chinese characters*?

I used `\CJKglue` to improve this but failed. Who has some more advice？

A working sample is as follows:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\begin{document}
大闹天宫始末

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe `\ziju{0.03em}` or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\ziju{<factor>}` works.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\CTEXnoindent
\begin{document}
    大闹天宫始末

    \ziju{0.3}
    大闹天宫始末
\end{document}
```

[image]